# Repeat values within for-loop for dictionary

Tags: python

I'm extracting a table from a webpage and want to include the player's ID, to match the length of the table. So, I can convert the dictionary into a pandas dataframe. However, it only adds the ID once for each table scraped.

For example:

```
test = defaultdict(list)
for j,i in enumerate(datas['data'][0:2]):
    p = i.split("/")[-1]
    url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/kylian-mbappe/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/{}'.format(p)
    r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    try:
        test[p].append(pd.read_html(r.content)[1])
        test['ID'].append(p)
        print('-------------------------------')
    except:
        continue
```

Where `p` has these values:

```
'543320', '415993'
```

I get something like:

```
{'543320': [  Season competition         competition.1   ... ID
              0  20/21         NaN         A-League Fin. ... 543320
              1  20/21         NaN              A-League  . 
              2  19/20         NaN              A-League  . 
              3  19/20         NaN               FFA Cup  . 
              4   2019         NaN  AFC Champions League  . 
              5  18/19         NaN              A-League  . 
              6  17/18         NaN         A-League Fin.  .
              7  17/18         NaN              A-League  . 
              8    NaN     Total :               Total :  .
```

But I was expecting:

```
{'543320': [  Season competition         competition.1   ... ID
              0  20/21         NaN         A-League Fin. ... 543320
              1  20/21         NaN              A-League ... 543320
              2  19/20         NaN              A-League ... 543320 
              3  19/20         NaN               FFA Cup ... 543320 
              4   2019         NaN  AFC Champions League ... 543320 
              5  18/19         NaN              A-League ... 543320 
              6  17/18         NaN         A-League Fin. ... 543320 
              7  17/18         NaN              A-League ... 543320 
              8    NaN     Total :               Total : ... 543320
```

Comment: would `test[p]['ID'].append(p)` work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `pd.read_html`, it returns a list of DataFrame. I think that you need to append the ID column before appending it to the list.

```py
test[p].append(pd.read_html(r.content)[1].assign(ID=p))
```

I haven't yet tested this but you could try. Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)